# Showing $χ$ for a three manifold?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-groups, geometric-topology

How would I show that the Euler number for $ (S^1 × S^1 × S^1) $ is $0$? 
Would it be different if we considered $S^2 × S^1 $ or just $S^3$? If so, how?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The Euler characteristic of $S^1$ is zero and the Euler characteristic of a product of spaces is the product of their Euler characteristic since $\chi(S^1)=0$, $\chi(S^1\times S^1\times S^1)=\chi(S^2\times S^1)=0$.

Comment: https://www.math.colostate.edu/~clayton/courses/601/601_7.pdf

Comment: You could do that, by using the [Künneth Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Künneth_theorem). You might want to take a deep dive into homology theory.

Comment: The reason that talking about cell complexes is preferable in this context to talking about simplicial complexes is because defining a simplicial structure on a product of complexes is [not a trivial task](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717322/product-of-simplicial-complexes), but for a product of CW complexes it's actually [pretty easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100170/cartesian-product-of-two-cw-complexes), and in particular it's not hard to count the number of cells and compute the Euler characteristic in terms of the factors.

Comment: What are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 1):

For the torus, you can also draw the space and count the number of 0,1,2, and 3 cells.  In particular, it can be constructed
from a cube by identifying each pair
of opposite square faces (see the picture below).  This gives 1 zero cell, 3 one cells, 3 two cells, and 1 three cell, which gives an Euler characteristic of $$1-3+3-1 = 0.$$

[image]

Comment: Have you heard about Poincaré Duality?