# Triangulating Product of Simplicial Complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

I am currently working on a problem for which I believe the following result is crucial.
[image]

The result of this problem was discussed in this post.

[Product of simplicial complexes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717322/product-of-simplicial-complexes)

However it is not clear to me why this construction works.

The definition of a simplicial complex that is used in the source of this problem is a collection of simplices in $\mathbb R^n$ which includes faces of its elements and such that its elements either intersect to give $\emptyset$ or another simplex in the collection.

Here it is obvious that the vertices in question are affinely independent, and that faces of elements of the collection are included in it, but I have not been able to show that the collection is stable under taking intersections.

Comment: Your link is broken: it just takes to me to the "ask a question" page, not to an existing post.

Comment: Apologies, I have now fixed the link.